# How to release NSTimer in ASCellNode

Tags: objective-c, asyncdisplaykit

I create a `NSTimer` in `ASCellNode`, when `ASTableView's` `UIViewController` pop, but the timer not be released.

```
_timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:3.0 target:self selector:@selector(autoScrollBanner) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
[[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] addTimer:_timer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
```

how can  i stop this timer? 
thx in advance!

Comment: So you want to know which method of the cell class, or super class, to add the timer release code?

Comment: @trojanfoe there is no method to trigger release this timer

Comment: What do you want to know then?

Answer (score 0):

Try overwrite next methods `didExitVisibleState`, `didExitDisplayState`,`didExitHierarchy` in ASCellNode inherited object and insert cancel fired timer.